# Keyboard not behaving in default mode (Software/OS side)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have an issue with my keyboard (Japanese Keyboard but I am sure it has nothing to do with localization). Whenever I use my <kbd>Del</kbd> key (delete key) that isn't in the numpad, it does nothing. And when I am editing a text and use the arrow keys (<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd>), the cursor (caret) moves to the beginning of the line or to the end respectively.

I had that issue in the past I don't recall what key combo I should press to fix this.

My keyboard is a Sanwa SKB-BT22BK (I am pretty sure it's not a hardware or keyboard firmware issue but I'm writing the reference just in case).

The OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look on the picture of that keyboard and to me it seems that the <kbd>Fn</kbd>key is pressed.
Meaning when you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> (non keypad) it will enable the scroll lock. When you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> arrow it will do "Home". The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key basically does the function mentioned in the blue text.

I didn't see a key for the Fn lock or to toggle the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key but it seems the most likely case.

In the manual it even states:

> 青色に印刷された機能を動作する時に押します

Translated this means:

> Press to activate the function printed in blue

Comment: You are right. Fn was somehow locked which is unusual. I'd never noticed the blue "Home" and "End" text on the arrow keys. it would have been a hint I guess (if I had).

Comment: @PaikuHan sadly I'm not very good in Japanese so I'm currently unable to try and find how to disable the toggle. Also if my message solved your question, please mark it as answer for future users looking for this.

Comment: you solved the issue. I don't thing there is a toggle lock thingy on the keyboard. Like I said this would be the second time it happened (last time was way back). As soon as I pressed "Fn" the issue got fixed. This could be caused by a firmware issue since sometimes after a short periode of inactivity, the bluetooth on the keyboard turn itself off. Also I've played a lot with the "Fn" key trying to figure out a few things before I built my own keyboard. Note that I did mark your answer as **The** Answer before I post my first comment.